# PyTorch transferring index to 1-0

Tags: pytorch

How to quickly set the elements in the given index list to 1 and others to 0?

For example,I have an ID pool like:
`torch.arange(10)`,
for a given input index `tensor([1,5,7,9,2])` wanna return `tensor([0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to start with `zeros` and fill with `ones` using fancy indexing like this:

```
import torch

tensor = torch.zeros(10)
tensor[[1, 5, 7, 9, 2]] = 1
```

If your IDs are predefined (e.g. `torch.arange(10)`) and you want to get only those elements which are not `zero` you can do this:

```
import torch

ids = torch.arange(10)

mask = torch.zeros_like(ids).bool() # it has to be bool
mask[[1, 5, 7, 9, 2]] = True

torch.masked_select(ids, mask)
```

Which would give you:

```
tensor([1, 2, 5, 7, 9])
```

Comment: Thanks Szymon, also I think use np.isin() is a way to solve this problem, but I'm not sure which one is faster.